# how to move current word caret position into previous word in richtextbox wpf?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, richtextbox

I am  writing a application using WPF C# Windows application.i want to navigate word by word in that richtextbox content.how to i done it.
i already tried to move current word to next word navigation.its work. i am using the below code.

```
TextPointer starting = txtAppendValue.Document.ContentStart;
            startval = txtAppendValue.CaretPosition;
            text = startval.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Backward);
            newWord = txtAppendValue.CaretPosition.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            if (newWord != null)
            {

                txtAppendValue.CaretPosition = newWord;
                txtptrCaret = txtAppendValue.CaretPosition;
                NextStringvalue = txtptrCaret.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                {
                    txtptrCaret = txtAppendValue.CaretPosition;
                    range1 = new TextRange(starting, txtptrCaret);
                    indexInText = range1.Text.Length;
                }}
```

this below line newword text pointer to give a next word to end of the content.

```
newWord = txtAppendValue.CaretPosition.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
```

So now how to i get an previous word and all other words text pointer?

**Note:** i already get the previous words using content start and caretposition.but it gives like strings. i want textpointer value to move each previous word.

Regards
Arjun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [MoveRightByWord](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.editingcommands.moverightbyword%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [MoveLeftByWord](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.editingcommands.moveleftbyword%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) commands for this:

```
EditingCommands.MoveLeftByWord.Execute(null, richTextBox);
```

According to the documentation, both commands are supported by RichTextBox.

Note, though, that when the input caret is *within* a word, this command moves it to the start of that word, not to the start of the previous word.

Comment: @Joey.thanks.I dont know,how it actullay helps me.Can you give any examples to get the previous word in richtextbox.

Comment: @arjunsanju: The point I was trying to make is that RichTextBox already knows how to do that by implementing the aforementioned commands. You can just tell the control to navigate to the previous or next word. The code I included does exactly that.

Comment: @Joey.k.but i want to highlight that word.so how can i get the index and length values for that word.

Comment: So you don't want to move the caret, you want to highlight a word. That sounds completely different to me. If selection suffices, there is a `SelectLeftByWord` command as well.

Comment: @Joey.thanks.I got answer using caretposition forward backward direction.